# Swift: WKWebView needs authentication.

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am trying to add an WKWebView to my app. Following the documentation, I implemented this:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "www.myurl.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

Now my Problem: The website I try to access needs an authentication. In safari I get asked for. But my app just presents The error "404 - this website doesnt exist". After searching I got the information that receiving a URLAuthenticationChallenge could solve the problem. With documentation and information from the internet, I added the following code:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    print("test if pass")
    let user = "*****"
    let password = "*****"
    let credential = URLCredential(user: user, password: password, persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
    challenge.sender?.use(credential, for: challenge)
}
```

I added the print statement to see if I get into my code. But after starting my app there is still the 404 error and nothing was printed to my console.

Can someone help me how I can add authentication? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your line,

```
let myURL = URL(string: "www.myurl.com")
```

with

```
let myURL = URL(string: "http://username:password@myURL.com/)
```

This help me for same issue as your's. Hope this help you too.

Comment: This works for me but I will wait for an answer without changing the url a little bit until I mark yours as the correct answer :)

Comment: @Sonius ok, thank you. try adding http:// to your url and take user name and password from webview delegate method as you did in question. for example: let myURL = URL(string: "http://www.myurl.com")

Comment: How can the code of @Sonius work without this at the end? `completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)`